# How do I prove the following equality?

Tags: binomial-theorem

$$ \frac{1}{(\omega - z)^n} - \frac{1}{\omega^n} =  \frac{z}{(\omega - z)^n\omega^n} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{n-k-1}(\omega-z)^k $$

I multiplied by $(\omega - z)^n\omega^n$ and arrived at the following equality I am struggling to prove

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k {n\choose k}\omega^{n-k-1}z^k =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\omega^{n-k-1}(\omega-z)^k.$$

Since the first equation is an (apparently) easy step in a prove it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 3):

Use the identity: $\displaystyle a^n-b^n = (a-b)\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a^kb^{n-k-1}\right)$ with $a = w$ and $b = w -z$

You can divide both sides by $b^n$ and identify it as a GP-sum in $a/b$.

Comment: Do you have a prove for the quoted identity?

Comment: @siwica yes, as I said if we divide both sides by $b^n$ we have $\displaystyle \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n - 1 = \left(\frac{a}{b} - 1\right)\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{a^k}{b^k}\right)$ which is a geometric sum with common ratio $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: oh nice, thats a simple prove and useful identity. I didn't get what you meant with your second line at first. Thank you!

Comment: @siwica welcome:)